# How to filter custom field array through get post meta then write to CSV

Tags: php, wordpress, csv, foreach

I have a code snippet that I use throughout my site, it reads the product IDs from a custom field `"menu_listing"` and displays content (like image, title, hyperlink, etc.) in an unordered list. I use this in various places on my site (ex. https://eatgoodathome.com/order/menu).

I am trying to get that list of product names to output next to customer order info in my Export Orders to CSV plugin. Here is the code pertaining to `"menu_listing"`.

```
global $post; 

// Date Range Parameters
   $today = date("Y-m-d");
   $next = date("Y-m-d", strtotime( "$today +2 weeks"));

// Query current menu based on date
   $menu_args = array(
        'post_type'=>'single_menu',
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
        'meta_query' => array( 
         array(
             'key' => "delivery_date",
             'value' =>  array( $today, $next ),
             'type'  => 'date',
             'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
             ),
         ));

// Display custom field
   $menu = new WP_Query( $menu_args );
   if ( $menu->have_posts() ) {
     while ( $menu->have_posts() ) {
                $menu->the_post();
            }

        // This is the custom field, content looks like this: [{"id":"9115"},{"id":"8256"},{"id":"8539"},{"id":"5586"}]
        $current_menu = json_decode( stripcslashes( get_post_field( "menu_listing", $post->id ) ) );


     if( $current_menu ){
           foreach( $current_menu as $single_block ) {

             if( $single_block->id ) { 
                      $dishes = get_post( $single_block->id )->post_title;
     }}}}

//Output CSV cells
    $row = array( $dishes );
```

In the state shown above, it loops through all the all the products, and only displays the name for the last one. I tried using implode(), explode(), an additional foreach() — those all seem to be a step in the wrong direction, outputting a blank column. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're reassigning the value of `$dishes` with each iteration which is why you're only seeing the name of the last item. Try doing this instead:

```
$dishes[] = get_post( $single_block->id )->post_title;
```

This way, you'll be creating a new index of the `$dishes` array every iteration instead of reassigning its value. Then you can just assign `$row = $dishes`.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, it improved the result but I am still not getting exactly what I need. `$dishes[]` repeats the menu listing of the first customer for all the remaining customers. `"menu_listing"` is actually `$menu_listing`, `"menu_listing_x"` changes for each customer (there are 5 possible variations). In my code, even though it reassigned the value of `$dishes`, it seemed to land on the correct last dinner. Example, everyone had "Miso-Glazed Salmon Sandwiches" except the customers who ordered no seafood, and their cell said "Tacos de Papa", which is correct, but incomplete.

Comment: @aleks1217 Is the `$current_menu` variable supposed to change with each iteration of the loop?

Comment: Yes, it should be different for each customer.

Comment: Basically, as a query produces all of the orders that are "processing", there is a loop (not shown above) that checks the product ID in their order and assigns the appropriate `$menu_listing` variable. That product array is `$current_menu`, which I want this loop to spit out the product names, rather than their IDs. This code works just fine on their email receipts and their My Account page in an unordered list, but I can't understand what is missing for this CSV export.

Comment: The code that works on other pages is exactly the same as what's in your question (aside from any cosmetic differences)? I was thinking the fact that you're getting the `$current_menu` outside of your while loop was the cause but I'm not so sure any more.

Comment: Yes, it's exactly the same, other than it's in a list. It's more like: `<ul> if($current_menu) {  foreach ($current_menu as single_block) { if ($single_block->id) { <li> get_post -> title </li> }} </ul>; }`

Comment: I'm feeling like the line item is giving it a reason to output, then loop and output, etc., but in this CSV export format it's just cycling through and spitting out only the last one.

Comment: And, to your point, if I move the bracket for the while loop, the results are the same.

Comment: What did you include within the while loop when you tried moving the brackets? If that's not the problem I'm not quite sure what is and I don't think I can figure it out without having all of your code. You should try debugging the loop to make sure all the values are set as you expect them to be.

Comment: I moved the bracket so it included the entire `if/foreach/if` statement. I really appreciate your help with this — I have been trying a bunch of things and nothing works. Here is a link of the full code: http://codepad.org/XMB8Fr9T. Here is a link to the CSV output: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GZLQgyr1osE8T_o0USf7tGX0q3FzohrQe7I-JTCHCi8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I cleaned up some of the non-essential columns, to inspect the code easier. But you can see here that this code http://codepad.org/m4dC8eZu outputs the correct product array for each order, based on their cart. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sZ2CWBmaiIMq4zT_xnNOXRT7gK0ItgPk4G5cU2bTv6k/edit?usp=sharing What I can't seem to get it to do, is convert the array into the product titles with the foreach statement.

Comment: Which version of PHP are you using?

Comment: PHP 5.6 – why does that matter?

Comment: In lower versions of PHP (I think 5.3 and lower) certain calls such as `get_post( $single_block->id )->post_title;` wouldn't behave as expected. You'd have to create a variable for the `get_post()` call and then reference the title.

Comment: I had been wondering about solutions like that ... Truth be told, to patch me for now, I just added a formula to my Excel spreadsheet to handle the ID to title conversion. Since I can't get this to work, it may be easiest to have the product meta added to customer's orders, and then call it up that way. Then it isn't dependent on the second loop (for date range and post type).

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort to assist me. I finally found a solution. :-)

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION: The code in my question looped through the array and only gave the last item in the array. My goal was to loop through each key/value pair, convert the value ("id") to title, and have each title populate a column for my csv. My solution involved scrapping the `foreach` statement, and requesting each array in the loop by its offset, then assigning it a column in the csv file.

```
    //Output for CSV
    $output = fopen('php://output', 'w');

if ( $menu->have_posts() ) {
 while ( $menu->have_posts() ) {
            $menu->the_post();
        }

    // This is the custom field, content looks like this: [{"id":"9115"},{"id":"8256"},{"id":"8539"},{"id":"5586"}]
    $current_menu = json_decode( stripcslashes( get_post_field( "menu_listing", $post->id ) ) );


    $dish1 =  get_post( $current_menu[0]->id )->post_title;
    $dish2 =  get_post( $current_menu[1]->id )->post_title;
    $dish3 =  get_post( $current_menu[2]->id )->post_title;

 // Validate for 4th array item, if exists
    if( sizeof($current_menu) === 4 ) {
    $dish4 =  get_post( $current_menu[3]->id )->post_title;
    } else {
    $dish4 =  "";
    }
}

//Output CSV cells
$row = array( $dish1, $dish2, $dish3, $dish4 );
        fputcsv( $output, $row );
```